# How do I return highest ID NON NULL field for a ```GROUP BY``` column?

Tags: mysql, sql

`SELECT email, first_name, last_name from person group_by email order by id desc`

If first_name has a mixture of values and nulls and how would I get the most recent NOT NULL value for the column?

```
id | email   | first_name   | last_name
1  | a@b.com |  ted         | smith
2  | a@b.com |  zed         | smith
3  | a@b.com |  NULL        | johnson
```

I basically want to get the value zed for first_name.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last" value unless you have a column specifying the ordering.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Updated with a quick sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for the help.

I found the answer I needed. You can actually put an order by in the GROUP_CONCAT!

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(first_name ORDER BY id desc), ',', 1) as recent_first_name`

It group concats `first_name` orders by id, then grabs the most recent one based on substring comma separation.

Also, what's cool is that `GROUP_CONCAT` filters `NULL` by default!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column such as `person_id` that has the ordering, you can simply do:

```
select p.*
from person p
where (email, person_id) in (select p2.email, max(p2.person_id)
                             from person p2
                             where p2.first_name is not null
                             group by p2.email
                            );
```

Comment: Does the max mean max parameter value or max order by row value. 
 Like if the number 5 was in row 1 and the number 3 was in row 2 and the order by was a descending on row id...would max return 5 or 3 for number?

Comment: @NickKiermaier max, and all other aggregate functions, operate on the value within the parenthesis. You need to stop thinking of rows having inherent "row ids" or order. Gordon's subquery is giving the highest person_id found for each email from among the rows in person that have a first_name that is not null). The IN is used to get the person records that yielded those max values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `suquery` here :

```
SELECT *
from person p
where id = (select max(id) 
            from person 
            where email = p.email and 
                  first_name is not null) 
order by id desc;
```